# Function with finite integral is finite a.e.

Tags: integration, measure-theory

I'm trying to understand the concept of integrals over general sets (instead of just $\mathbb{R}$, or just $\mathbb{N}$ with the counting measure).

Let $(\Omega, A, \mu)$ be a measure space and let $f: \Omega \to [0, \infty]$ be $A$-measurable. Assume that the integral exists:

$$ \int_{\Omega} f d\mu $$

My question is: if $S = \{x \in \Omega : f(x) = \infty\}$, is the measure $S$ zero? (So that $f$ is finite a.e.) Intuitively, I think, the answer is yes, because otherwise, we would have (I think!)

$$ \int_{S} f d\mu = \infty $$

but this would be a contradiction, since $S \subset \Omega$ gives us

$$ \infty = \int_{S} f d\mu < \int_{\Omega} f d\mu < \infty $$

If my intuition is correct, please give a formal proof of the second formula; I am having a hard time with (in a formal way) dealing with the concept of an integral over a general set with respect to a general measure.

Answer (score 7):

The canonical solution is to note that

$$ Z = \{ |f| =\infty\} = \bigcap_{n\geqslant 1} \{ |f|\geqslant n\}$$

and that for every $n$,

$$\mu(Z)  =\int_{Z}1d\mu \leqslant \int_{|f|\geqslant n}1d\mu \leqslant \frac{1}{n} \int_{X} |f|\to 0 $$

as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $E=\{x \in X, |f(x)|=\infty\}$. Note that $\infty \cdot \chi_{E}\leq |f|$, hence $$\infty \cdot\mu(E)\leq \int |f| < \infty$$

That implies $\mu(E)=0$.

Comment: Do we really want to introduce an inequality of the form $\infty\cdot \chi_E\leqslant |f|$ if we can avoid it?