# How to determine that the limit of a sequence of functions is limited?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be a measurable space.

$u \in \mathcal M_{\bar{\mathbb R}}^+ (\mathcal A)$
where $\mathcal M_{\bar{\mathbb R}}^+ (\mathcal A)$ denotes the families of positive extended real-valued measureable functions $c:(X,\mathcal A)\rightarrow(\bar{\mathbb R} , \mathscr B(\bar{\mathbb R})$, where $\mathscr B$ denotes Borel.
(Note that $\bar{\mathbb R}$ is the closure of $\mathbb R$, i.e. $[-\infty, \infty]$).

Also let $(u_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a series of functions in 
$\mathcal M_{\bar{\mathbb R}}^+ (\mathcal A)$, under the following conditions:

$$
u_n \rightarrow u ~\text{for}~ n\rightarrow \infty, ~~~~~ 
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_X u_n\, d\mu = c, ~~ c\in\mathbb R
$$

How can I from the above determine that 
$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}  u_n$ is finite?

**My thinking**

We know that $u_n$ is measurable, and that the limit of the integral is finite.
I feel that I can somehow use this to show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}  u_n$ is finite, but I am not sure how to go about it.

---

I don't understand the results in [this SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2024585/function-with-finite-integral-is-finite-a-e), but it might be useful?

Comment: What is $\mathcal M^+_{\bar{\Bbb R}}$?

Comment: Of course you can deduce $u_n \to u$, if you assume $u_n \to u$, as $n \to \infty$??

Comment: @AOrtiz good point - fixed

Comment: @JuliusL33t I don't follow - that is not what I want to show, I want to show that the limit is finite

Comment: @TokeFaurby Never mind, I read only half your question... :(

Comment: When you say $u_n\to u$, is that pointwise, uniform, etc?

Comment: I am not sure, but I believe that it is point-wise. Does it change the result?

Answer (score 1):

It is likely meant that $u_n\to u$ pointwise $\mu$-almost-everywhere. Here is a suggested approach using Fatou’s lemma and Tchebychev’s inequality. All my integrals will be with respect to the measure $\mu$, so $\displaystyle\int(\dots)$ means $\displaystyle\int(\dots)\, d\mu$.

By Fatou's lemma, write
$$\int u = \int \lim u_n = \int \liminf u_n \le \liminf \int u_n = \lim \int u_n = c.$$
If $N\ge 1$, by Tchebychev's inequality, $\displaystyle\mu\big( \{u > N\} \big) \le \frac{1}{N}\int u \le \frac{c}{N}$. Notice that $\{ u = \infty \} = \bigcap_{N=1}^\infty \{u > N\}$.

Do you see how to take it from here?

Comment: I don't quite understand the step from $\lim \inf \int u_n = \lim \int u_n$. How do you know that equality?

Comment: @TokeFaurby It's because of the assumption that $\lim \int u_n$ exists. If $a_n$ is a sequence of numbers such that $\lim a_n$ exists and is finite, then $\liminf a_n = \limsup a_n$, and their common value is $\lim a_n$.

Comment: So in this case $a_n = \int u_n$?

Comment: @TokeFaurby Yes, that's right.

Comment: Just to be sure that I understand - the reason is that $\int_X u_n \text d \mu$ are measurable functions?

Comment: @TokeFaurby I don't understand your latest question. The reason about what?

Comment: Sorry - I am using a lemma in my book for $\lim \inf \int a_n= \lim \int a_n$, but it explicitly states that it is only valid if $a_n$  are measurable functions. So my question is: is the reason why the equality holds is that $a_n$ are measurable functions? So it was just a clarifying question to your first comment - how do we know that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84065/discussion-between-aortiz-and-toke-faurby).